# "window is not defined" service worker

Tags: javascript, django, service-worker

I am trying to register a service worker for my django project. This is the code I am using for registration:

```
<!-- register service worker -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register("{% url 'sw.js' %}").then(function(registration) {
        console.log("Service worker registered.");
        console.log("Registered at: "+registration.scope);
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

and this is the code in my service_worker.js:

```
// App install banner
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
  e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult) {
    console.log(choiceResult.outcome);

    if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed') {
      console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
    } else {
      console.log('User added to home screen');
    }
  });
});
```

I see this error in console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined`

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to use the Debugger set to "Break on exceptions" to find out which line is being executed and under what context? At first-glance it sounds like your Registration script is being executed in a ServiceWorker context (where `window` is not available).

Comment: @Dai It is stopping at this line window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e). I don't know if it is related but in the Application tab, the service worker doesn't show the file name but shows (index). I am using django and I am rendering the service worker as a template.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was writing the code:

```js
// App install banner
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(e) {
    e.userChoice.then(function(choiceResult){
        console.log(choiceResult.outcome);
        if(choiceResult.outcome == 'dismissed'){
            console.log('User cancelled home screen install');
        }else{
            console.log('User added to home screen');
        }
    });
});
```

in service_worker.js file. The service workers don't have access to DOM elements like `window` or `document`. Once I put the above code in a separate js file associated to the html file, it worked. I am new to PWAs and the concept of service workers and this seems like a newbie mistake. I am posting this answer should it help someone else.

Comment: @Vishal I have lost the code. Do you need help with any specific part?

Comment: I got solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Vishal can you please share the solution you got

Comment: I use `window` in this commands: `var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);` and  `if (window.screen.width >= 1200)` and I get this exact same error.
how do I fix it?